# Can i remove Google Analytics e-commerce transaction from the the web interface?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to remove some erroneous transactions from the Google Analytics Ecommerce page (https://www.google.com/analytics/reporting/transactions), how could I do that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently. You can negative the transaction, but not remove, which is a pain because it adds the negative to the current week of transactions, vs, negative on the date of transaction.